# Full resolution WebView on Android TV

Tags: android-tv

On a 1080p emulator and Smart TV (nVidia Shield) I only get a 960x540 WebView. Is it possible to use the whole resolution available instead?

[image]

Comment: @jaydroider found the mistery. The devicePixelRatio is 2!

Comment: Have you got solved your issue ?

Comment: yes. Being the pixel density double, 960x540 equals to full HD.

Comment: Did you fix it? How?

Comment: Any fixes for this? I have an app in 1080p, with fixed UI I do not want to change my UI to fit 960x540.

Comment: @ToM See answer below, to get access to the pixels available multiply resolution for devicePixelRatio

Comment: @Nuthinking yes I know how to check devicePixelRatio, however I cannot change it. My use case is that I have a UI in 1080p (which is fixed) and I don't want to downscale it manually to 960x540. Is there a way to change the webview to use full 1080p?

Comment: @ToM of course you can't change devicePixelRatio, you should change your assets/elements accordingly. In my case, for instance, I made the canvas width equals to the width returned by the browser times devicePixelRatio. Then I fixed its width to the original value via CSS.

Comment: @Nuthinking your solution works perfectly with canvas, that is easily scaled. My problem was different, but I fund a bit hackish solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HDTV using Android TV is considered as 960x540px display with 2x pixel ratio. Not sure how a 4k TV is recognized, but to use all the pixels, check window.devicePixelRatio .

Answer (score 2):

Im looking for an answer to the same question, but i can confirm the following.

1080p TV Testing

each device configured in setting to only use 1080p 60Hz

Amazon Firestick gets 960 x 540 px in all browsers tested.

Shield TV gets 960 x 540 px in all browsers tested.

new Amazon Fire TV Cube gets 960 x 540 px in all browsers tested.

4K TV Testing

Amazon Firestick (not 4K compatible) gets 960 x 540 px in all browsers tested.

Shield TV (with output setting at 4K 60Hz) gets 960 x 540 px in all browsers tested.

new Amazon Fire TV Cube (with output setting 4K 60Hz) gets 960 x 540 px in all browsers tested.

whats more bizarre is that both 1080p and 4K test the reported pixelratio
was 2. I at least expected to see a  pixel ratio of 4 on 960x540 on 4K

I use TVs connected to PC to display large tables of status data.
when fully utilized a 70" 4K TV displays hundreds of  different bits of info, its a beautiful thing.

then you get an Nvidia Shield because its "4K" and discover the browser renders at 960 x 540, and the page that looks fantastic in 4K looks like blocky illegible crap.

Comment: Are you basically saying that browsers in Android TV can't render at 4k? Yeah, it would make sense for the pixel ratio to be set to 4.

Comment: Any fixes for this? I have an app in 1080p, with fixed UI and I do not want to change my UI to fit 960x540. Is there a way to allow 720p or 1080p in Android TV WebView?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did in Android TV 28
My app original resolution is 1080p

JS Code:

```
document.body.style.zoom = 1/window.devicePixelRatio
```

Comment: if the whole UI was designed for 1080p, I guess this could be a quick fix. Still a bit hackish though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebView#setInitialScale to scale the website according to your needs. To get wanted scale you can use the code:

```
Point metrics = new Point();
((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(WIDNOW_SERVICE)).getDisplay(metrics);
int scale = (int) (((double) metrics.x) / 3840/*SCREEN_WIDTH*/ * 100);
```

You should not set additional settings like setUseWideViewPort, because it can overwrite/ignore the scale setting.

Answer (score 0):

After all, someone managed to work with a resolution other than 960 x 540?
It's pretty weird having a 60 inch tv with such a small resolution.

Comment: devicePixelRatio makes all the difference. It's a multiplier. iPhones, for instance, multiply times 3. My guess is that your devicePixelRatio is 4. Meaning that if you want to show a drawn canvas at full resolution, it has to be 3840x2160 and then scaled to 25% down via CSS.