# SmartTV web application

Tags: web-applications, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, smart-tv

I am trying to choose and develop a web app for a SmartTV with the following requirments:

Resolution supported: 4k
Development: web technologies (html, javascript, css)

I have tried a sample samsung tizen os web app but it only goes up to 1080p resolution.

Does anyone have any recommendation for smartTV brand that supports 4k resolution web apps.

TIA

Comment: Playstation 4 Pro and PS5 both support video playback resolutions of 4k, however in order to develop an app on either of these platforms you would need to sign an agreement with Sony and get hold of dedicated test hardware. I don't know of any other platform that suopports 4k video yet inside a web view.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about hardware recommendations, not programming.

Answer (score 2):

At least the main TV manufacturers (LG and Samsung) don't support 4K apps. Maybe your can check their developer websites to check the specifications

By the way, you need to differentiate the app UI resolution and the media playback resolution (i.e. apps for 4K models use 1080 for the UI with 4K media playback capacities)

[Tizen specifications](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/specifications/general-specifications.html)

[WebOs specifications](https://webostv.developer.lge.com/discover/specifications/supported-app-resolution/)

For Android TV apps, depends of the solution (native android or webview based) but you said web technologies must be used so you should check the specific behaviour of webview based apps like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960108/full-resolution-webview-on-android-tv)

Best regards